# join two tables with multiple columns wirh same column id

Tags: mysql

So I have these two  tables

I have tried to join with union and tired with case it didn't work.

```
Table f
  A    B     C    D
  1  "val" "val"  4

Table g
  A    B     C    D
  1  "cal" "dal"  5
  2  "cal" "dal"  5
```

so I want the result as

```
  A      B           C      f.D    g.D
  1  "val cal"   "val dal"   4      5
  2   "cal"        "dal"    null    5
```

Comment: Hello, we need you to share what you have tried so far so we can help. I would suggest you to use a `left join` since one of the table record may be optional. And you also need CONCAT, check it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: Could you show what you tried already? [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Use outer joins:

```sql
SELECT g.A, f.B, g.B, f.C, g.C, f.D, g.D
FROM g LEFT OUTER JOIN f ON g.A = f.A;
```

This won't let you concatenate the `A` and `B` columns from both table `g` and `f`. That would have to be done in code.

Comment: You can use the `CONCAT` function to concatenate the values from the different tables.